# Zend Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' on Plesk Server

Tags: php, zend-framework2, plesk

I am getting the following warning and error on a plesk server where I am trying to get the Zend framework working:

```
PHP Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test.php on line 5 
PHP Fatal error: require_once() [function.require-once]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/local/PEAR/:/usr/share/zend') in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test.php on line 5
```

I have set the `include_path` in the php.ini file (/etc/php.ini) to use the directory where I have added the Zend files (/usr/share/zend). This directory then has the framework in a sub-dir called Zend.

I have tried adding a slash to the end of the `include_path` (/usr/share/zend/).

The path is present when I use `get_include_path()`

I have tried using `set_include_path`.

The /usr/share/zend directory has 775 permissions (also tried with 777) and the user and group are both set to root.

I would like to have the framework available to all sites on the server.

I have copied in the Gdata files too and the Zend/Loader.php is there.

Versions:

- Framework: 2.0.4
- Gdata: 1.12.0

This is the PHP:

```
require_once("Zend/Loader.php");
```

I have also tried using:

```
require_once("/usr/share/zend/Zend/Loader.php");
```

I am novice plesk/unix user

Comment: it is file access permissions issue most likely. But that can be open_basedir php directive restriction as well. I think it should have stated so in error though if it was the case.

Comment: Des the file /usr/share/zend/Zend/Loader.php exist?

Comment: @RobAllen: safe_mode was on I set it to off and hey presto it worked! Thank you. Not sure to credit you for the answer...

Comment: @RobAllen - sorry meant, not sure *how* to credit you for the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things to check for are:

- The file exists where PHP is looking for it.
- The file is readable by the web server/php_fpm process.
- safe_mode is off!

(Putting the information here - so that the question can be marked as answered!)

Answer (score 0):

Zend/Loader.php is for ZF1 and that file don't exists with ZF2 (2.0.4)

Also you need to download the updated version of GData compatible with ZF2

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData

If you'll use Composer to setup your dependencies then you should use `require_once __DIR__ . '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: Thanks @Maks3w. Now that it's all working I will use the latest version.